# Como instanciar objetos utilizando sintaxe de objeto literal?

Tags: javascript, objetos

Tenho uma dúvida talvez um pouco estupida, mas vamos lá, em Javascript, posso criar uma instancia de um objeto declarando assim, vamos num exemplo de um jogo, onde tenho que instaciar balas para atirar no inimigo:

```
var Bala = {
      myFunctionInit: function myFunctionInit(){
          console.log("Pul!");
      },
      x = 0,
      y = 0,
      speed = 0
};
```

mas então eu quero poder instanciar várias dessas balas, porém não posso fazer algo como:

```
var outraBala = new Bala;
```

e entendo o porque não posso, pois a Bala já é um objeto instancia, isso pude ver dando um "console.log(Bala);", a questão é, como eu posso instanciar a Bala, de maneira correta declarando objetos dessa forma?

Sei que posso fazer:

```
var outraBala = Object.assign({}, Bala);
```

Pensei também em colocar o objeto literal Bala como retorno de uma função, e assim poder instanciar ele assim:

```
var Bala = function(x, y, speed) {
      return = {
          myFunctionInit: function myFunctionInit(){
              console.log("Pul!");
          },
          x: x,
          y: y,
          speed: speed
       };
}
var outraBala = Bala(1, 1, 10);
```

mas não tenho certeza se é a melhor maneira de lidar com essa situação.

*obs: não quero instanciar objetos usando class, dessa maneira eu sei como fazer, quero poder criá-los desta maneira declarativa(que pessoalmente acho que é a mais clara de todas) e instanciá-los da melhor forma possivel, e se for estupidez minha, preciso entender o porque.*

Comment: Você quer instanciar um objeto várias vezes, não seria o caso de uma função construtora?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam como a que fiz(`var Bala = function(x, y, speed) {...`)?

Comment: Com algumas correções, a função que fez recebe 3 parâmetros mas não os usa, em vez de `=` é `:` dentro do objeto retornado

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam corrigi lá, eu viajei mesmo com o "=" e esqueci de atribuir os parâmetros XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como disse que não quer usar `class` do javascript terá que fazer uma função construtora, para instanciar tem algumas opções:

Usar o operador `new`:

```js
function Bala(x, y, speed) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.speed = speed;
}

let bala1 = new Bala(0, 0, 10);
let bala2 = new Bala(5, 5, 20);
let bala3 = new Bala(3, 0, 1);

console.log(bala1, bala2, bala3);
```

Retornar diretamente o objeto (acredito que é isso que deseja):

```js
function Bala(x, y, speed) {
  return {
    x: x,
    y: y,
    speed: speed
  };
}

let bala1 = Bala(0, 0, 10);
let bala2 = Bala(5, 5, 20);
let bala3 = Bala(3, 0, 1);

console.log(bala1, bala2, bala3);
```

Ambos vão dar na mesma, já que, por baixo dos panos, o operador `new` pega o `this` da função contrutora, ou seja, o primeiro exemplo é equivalente a:

```js
function Bala(x, y, speed) {
  let object = {};
  object.x = x;
  object.y = y;
  object.speed = speed;

  return object;
}

let bala1 = Bala(0, 0, 10);
let bala2 = Bala(5, 5, 20);
let bala3 = Bala(3, 0, 1);

console.log(bala1, bala2, bala3);
```